# my code works but it does not give me what I want

Tags: c++

my code is going to take ten numbers and separate the numbers to two groups : odd and positive numbers

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int odd(int a)
{
if (a % 2 != 0)
        {
            return a;
        }
}

int pos(int p)
{
if (p >= 0)
        {
    return p;
        }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int entery[10];
    
    cout << "please enter ten number : ";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)

    {

        cin >> entery[i];

        }
    
    cout << "the odd numbers are : \n" << odd(entery[i]);
         
    cout << "your positive numbers are : \n" << pos(entery[i]);
}
```

it it somehow works but the odd number is always 0
and the positive number always is -858993460

I use it without array and both groups become zero

Comment: Your `odd` and `pos` functions do not return a value when the condition is `false`. That makes your program have _undefined behavior_.  Instead do: `bool odd(int) { return a%2 != 0; }` and `bool pos(int p) { return p >= 0; }`

Comment: -858993460 = 0xCCCCCCCC which means you're reading uninitialized memory: [When and why will a compiler initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: *my code works but it does not give me what I want*: it means that it does not work. The code merely *compiles*, but due to the number of errors invoking undefined behavior, is not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes your code corrected. Just to let you know, your code wasn't checking all the possible conditions inside `odd` and `pos` functions. It just was returning something when the condition was `false`.
I modified these functions, making it work with a `bool` now instead of a number. In your `main` method, now, when this functions returns a `true`, it will print the number, but won't do it if it's returning a `false`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
bool odd(int a) { return a % 2 != 0; }

bool pos(int p) { return p >= 0; }

int main()
{
    int i;
    int entery[10];
    
    cout << "Please enter ten numbers: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> entery[i];
    
    cout << "The odd numbers are : ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (odd(entery[i]))
            cout << entery[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << "\nYour positive numbers are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (pos(entery[i]))
            cout << entery[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

If you want to change your program in the future, you can change the `for` to make it work while `sizeof(entery)/sizeof(entery[0])`, so it will iterate the array looking at the size instead of the number `10`.

Comment: The return value from `odd` and `pos` would be better as `bool` instead of `int`

Comment: @TedLyngmo `odd` and `pos` methods in my code are working/returning with a `bool` var. I'm not sure what you mean. Can I have a better explanation?

Comment: I mean, `bool odd(int a);` and `bool pos(int p);` - there's no reason to convert the `bool` you have inside the function to an `int` that will then be used as a `bool` in boolean context afterwards. Stay with `bool` all the way. You could also simplify both functions: `bool odd(int a) { return a % 2 != 0; }` and `bool pos(int p) { return p >= 0; }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo ooops! You're right!! Didn't notice at first, copy-paste issues, I guess. It's corrected now. Thanks!!